# Call a python function in Django and display the results on the same page

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-templates

I'm a beginner to django and I'm trying to perform a cipher operation, but what I want to do is whenever I press the cipher button it should compute the logic and display the results on the same page i.e. my homepage. It'd be really great if someone could help me out.
This is my html template

```
    <h1>PRODUCT CIPHER</h1>

    <form action="">
        <label>
            Enter Message Here: <input name="message" type="text"><br><br>
            Enter key for Shift: <input name="shiftKey" type="number"><br><br>
            Enter key for transpose: <input name="transKey" type="number"><br>
            For transposition 1->Reverse and 2->Even Odd<br><br>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Encrypt" name="Cipher"><br>
        <p>{{ encrypted_message }}</p><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Decrypt" name="Cipher">
        <p>{{ decrypted_message }}</p>
    </form>
```

Views.py

```
def perform_cipher(request):
    if request.GET['Cipher'] == 'Encrypt':
        msg_dict = {}
        message = request.GET['message']
        shiftKey = int(request.GET['shiftKey'])
        transKey = int(request.GET['transKey'])
        msg_dict['encrypted_message'] = cipher.encrypt(message, shiftKey, transKey)
        return render(request, 'home.html', msg_dict)
    else:
        decrypt = {'plain_text': cipher.decrypt()}
        return render(request, 'home.html', decrypt)
```

home.html is the above html code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your view code so far too. Also, if you're a beginner, have you walked through the Django tutorial? It's quite good.

Comment: @AKX I haven't gone through the official tutorials, I'll go through it for sure